# How to extract data from SAP through SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, etl, sap-erp

Where to find the .NET Data Provider for mySAP™ Business Suit?

What are the prerequisites of extracting data from SAP?

Do I need to install anything on SAP too for extracting data from SAP through SSIS?

How to connect to SAP in SSIS?

Thank you so much in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can gain access to the database on the backend, that would be easier for SSIS to extract from.  That's what we do where I work.  You can use the SAP .NET connector and write a Windows Service or Console App to extract data through RFC function module calls.

I have posted an example of a simple RFC call here:
 http://scn.sap.com/thread/1876430.

More detailed tutorial can be found here:
http://scn.sap.com/community/interoperability-microsoft-net/blog/2013/02/14/connecting-to-sap-with-nco-3

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you should NOT access SAP underlying database directly. I explained extensively in this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56152541/extracting-data-from-sap-to-sql-server/56658748#56658748)